# Adding a specific title to list of abbreviations / acronyms in LaTeX

Tags: lists, titles, acronyms

If I have the following code to handle generating a list of acronyms in LaTeX

```
\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist]{glossaries} % Makes a list of abbreviations.
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\include{Glossary}
\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{mcolindex}
```

Which is being printed using:

```
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
```

I am given the title `Acronyms` above the list of acronyms. Is it possible to specify my own title for the list instead?

Because I want the list appearing after other 'List of...' sections as follows:

```
List of Figures
List of Tables
List of Abbreviations
```

Which would be more consistent than:

```
List of Figures
List of Tables
Acronyms
```

If I use:

```
% Print glossary.
\glsaddall
\printglossary[title={List of abbreviations}]
```

Then no glossary is printed in the report and I have the following in the log:

```
Command Line:   makeindex.exe -s "Main.ist" -t "Main.glg" -o "Main.gls" "Main.glo"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\Mr Morgan\Documents\College\PhD\Thesis

This is makeindex.exe, version 2.14 [02-Oct-2002] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file C:/Users/Mr Morgan/Documents/College/PhD/Thesis/Main.ist...........................done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file Main.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in Main.gls.
Transcript written in Main.glg.


Command Line:   makeindex.exe -s "Main.ist" -t "Main.alg" -o "Main.acr" "Main.acn"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\Mr Morgan\Documents\College\PhD\Thesis

This is makeindex.exe, version 2.14 [02-Oct-2002] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file C:/Users/Mr Morgan/Documents/College/PhD/Thesis/Main.ist...........................done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file Main.acn....done (13 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (43 comparisons).
Generating output file Main.acr....done (38 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in Main.acr.
Transcript written in Main.alg.
```

Comment: `\printglossary` prints the `main` glossary by default. Since you have used the `acronym` package option, the list of acronyms are in the `acronym` glossary, in which case you need to specify this `\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]`

Comment: Thanks Nicola. It works perfectly but is it possible to add paragraph text to the glossary? I mean something that prints below the title, not a paragraph per entry.

Comment: I have done the text in the glossary using `\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{Text...}`

Comment: Renewing `\glossarypreamble` (as in your comment) before `\printglossary` should work. If it doesn't, you'll need to ask a new question with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: No need, it works quite adequately. Thanks Nicola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only use the `acronym` package option, as I assume from your code above, using

```
\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]
```

instead of

```
\printglossaries
```

should do the trick.

If you use multiple glossaries, you will have to repeat the `\printglossary[]` command for each glossary.

Comment: There is only one glossary and that is likely to remain the case. But it's rather odd because if use `\printglossary[title={List of Abbreviations}]`, my glossary doesn't print?

Comment: Does it give an error or does the glossary simply not show up? Also, rerunning `makeglossaries\xindy\makeindex` might help. By the way, a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe) could help here.

Comment: Details appended to question. I'm not sure about the use of `makeglossaries\xindy\makeindex`.

Comment: From the log output, makeindex generates the list of acronyms. Try the following: `\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]`.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen that. I updated the answer.