# Adding headings in contents causes links to wrong page

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, page-numbering

I have a document with a standard TOC generated automatically by `pdflatex` but by default this TOC does not include lists of figures, tables and the bibliography.

So I am trying to force these manually using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}` in the preamble, e.g.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
```

But what I am finding is that although the lists are included in the TOC, the page numbers tend to be one less than they should be. So if the TOC shows the `List of Tables` on page iv, the link in the TOC takes me to page iv which is titled `List of Figures`. In the TOC, the `List of Figures` is given as page iii.

The LaTeX MWE below illustrates what is happening.

A related issue is the page number of the bibliography. The TOC shows it to be on page 14 but page 14 actually displays the `Results` chapter.

The body of the document is fine and the titles appear correctly on the pages. So it must be something I am not doing, or doing wrong, with the `\addcontentsline{...}` lines.

Can anyone suggest anything?

**MWE code:**

```
    \documentclass[oneside,12pt]{report} % Use twoside for alternate page headings.

\usepackage{uolthesis}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
% \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{footmisc}
% \usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
% \usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}

\marginsize{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}{2.54cm}

% LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist]{glossaries} % Makes a list of abbreviations.
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{Text to go here\ldots}

% LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS. --------------------------------------------------------------------------

% NOTE: The LaTeX glossary is in file Abbreviations.tex. The thesis glossary is in file Glossary.tex.

% With thanks to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197692/adding-a-specific-title-to-
%                 list-of-abbreviations-acronyms-in-latex.

\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist]{glossaries} % Makes a list of abbreviations.
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
% \makeglossaries % This must be run from the command-line: e.g. 'makeglossaries file'
                  % where `file` is the name of the main LaTeX file.
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{Some text\ldots}

\include{DummyGlossary}
% \renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{mcolindex}
% \glossarystyle{long}

% PART, CHAPTER AND SECTION NUMBERING.  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter

\let\LaTeXStandardPart\part%
\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@noopt}[1]{%
    \unstarredpart@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@opt}[2][]{%
    \cleardoublepage% (For clearing content before.)
    \begingroup%
    \let\newpage\relax%
    \LaTeXStandardPart[#1]{#2}%
    \endgroup%
}

\newcommand{\starredpart}[1]{%
    \LaTeXStandardPart*{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredpart}{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\unstarredpart@@opt}{\unstarredpart@@noopt}%
}

\renewcommand{\part}{%
  \@ifstar{\starredpart}{\unstarredpart}%
}

% BIBLIOGRAPHY PREAMBLE. --------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{The references below are listed in order of author(s).}

% BEGIN DOCUMENT. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

    \pagenumbering{roman}

    % Title page.
    \title{\textcolor{red}{** WORKING DRAFT **}}
    \author{Author}

    \begin{abstract}
        This report\ldots
    \end{abstract}

    % LISTINGS. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \tableofcontents

    % Print glossary.
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}    
    \printglossaries%[title={List of abbreviations}]

    % Print algorithms. 
    \clearpage% or \clearpage under the oneside option
    \phantomsection% Mark a hyperref link location
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}% Add contents entry for List of Tables
    \listofalgorithms% Start List of Tables
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}

    % Print figures.    
    \clearpage% or \clearpage under the oneside option
    \phantomsection% Mark a hyperref link location
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}% Add contents entry for List of Tables
    \listoffigures% Start List of Tables

    % Print tables.           
    \clearpage% or \clearpage under the oneside option
    \phantomsection% Mark a hyperref link location
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}% Add contents entry for List of Tables
    \listoftables% Start List of Tables

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \chapter{Introduction}

    Some text for the second reference \cite{Date}.

    \noindent Some text for the first reference \cite{Abiteboul_et_al}.

    \noindent Some text for the first reference \cite{Paass_et_al}.

    \noindent Abbreviations W3C and WWW.

    \chapter{Background}
    \chapter{Review}

    \part{Case study one}
    \chapter{Apparatus}
    \chapter{Method}
    \chapter{Experiment}
    \chapter{Results}

    \part{Case study two}
    \chapter{Apparatus}
    \chapter{Method}
    \chapter{Experiment}
    \chapter{Results}

    \appendix

    % Print figures.
    \clearpage% or \clearpage under the oneside option
    \phantomsection% Mark a hyperref link location
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}% Add contents entry for List of Tables
    \bibliography{DummyBibliography}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}



\end{document}
```

And bibliography:

```
@book{Abiteboul_et_al,
  author = {S. Abiteboul and P. Buneman and D. Suciu},
  title = {Data on the web: From relations to semi-structured data and XML},
  publisher = {Morgan-Kaufmann},
  address = {San Francisco, CA, USA},
  year = {2000}
}

@book{Date,
  author    = {C. J. Date},
  title     = {{An Introduction to Database Systems, 6th Edition}},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year      = {1995},
  isbn      = {0-201-82458-2},
  timestamp = {Thu, 03 Jan 2002 11:51:07 +0100},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/books/aw/Date95},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org
}

@inproceedings{Paass_et_al,
  author    = {Gerhard Paa\ss and
               Edda Leopold and
               Martha Larson and
               J{\"{o}}rg Kindermann and
               Stefan Eickeler},
  title     = {{SVM Classification Using Sequences of Phonemes and Syllables}},
  booktitle = {Principles of Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery, 6th European Conference,
               {PKDD} 2002, Helsinki, Finland, August 19-23, 2002, Proceedings},
  year      = {2002},
  pages     = {373--384},
  crossref  = {DBLP:conf/pkdd/2002},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45681-3_31},
  doi       = {10.1007/3-540-45681-3_31},
  timestamp = {Fri, 12 Sep 2014 20:22:12 +0200},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/pkdd/PaassLLKE02},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}
}
```

Comment: Add `\addcontentsline` after `\listof...`

Comment: Should I retain the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}` lines?

Comment: `\listoftables\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}`

Comment: Try with `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{\listtablename}\listoftables`...

Comment: @Sigur: This works in the general case but happens in the case of my glossary code, i.e. 

    `\glsaddall   
     \printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}`


And how might it be added to bibliography code?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Insert list of figures in the table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48509/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be on the correct page before you can issue contents-related macros. For this use

```
\cleardoublepage% or \clearpage under the oneside option
\phantomsection% Mark a hyperref link location
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}% Add contents entry for List of Tables
\listoftables% Start List of Tables
```

One would do something similar for the ToC, the LoF and whichever other `\chapter`-related entry that is not in the ToC already.

If you want all list-of elements added to the ToC, you can also just add the [`tocbibind` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) to your preamble.

Comment: I am using tocbibind, but I get the Contents in the TOC, and am uncertain about how to apply `tocbibind` to the lists of algorithms and abbreviations. The other two lists appear to work.

Comment: @MrMorgan: Your example code doesn't show the use of `tocbibind`. Regardless, in order to get the other lists in the ToC, use my manual suggestion in the answer.